# OWIN startup class works on one server but doesn't work on another server

Tags: sitecore, owin, hangfire

I have a sitecore project. I set up the hangfire framework to schedule some tasks so I have a startup class like this:

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(sample.Startup))]
namespace sample
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            try
            {
                app.UseHangfireDashboard();
                app.UseHangfireServer();                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

This class works on our development server but it doesn't work on our acceptance server. both servers use the same windows and same IIS. Is there something else I have to do to make this works?

Comment: Do you have the 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb' package installed on the acceptance box?  If this is in a separate class library, and depending o your deployment process, it's possible that the required DLLs are not making it into the Sitecore solution. Try installing the OWIN package on the Sitecore project as well.

Comment: @AmirSetoudeh:  Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb' package is installed on the sitecore project. the strange thing is that this setup is working on development server but doesn't work on acceptance server with the same windows and iis versions

Comment: I would suggest you move the code from Owin/startup to a custom processor in the Stecore `Initialize` pipeline. You may also want to consider [SiteCron module](http://www.akshaysura.com/2015/06/23/sitecron-sitecore-module-for-your-everyday-scheduling-needs/) as an alternative.

Comment: @jammykam: its the companies policy to use hangfire for all projects. I need to use the owin middleware to prepare the hangfire dashboard.

Comment: Sometimes ASP.NET isn't registered in IIS correctly, and you should run the `aspnet_regiis -i` command.